# batch script to search and find file, then replace string

Tags: batch-file

Trying to create a batch script that can find the file on each user's profile, and then replace a certain string within that file. The location of the file is: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Sage Software\Sage MAS 500\application.config`

I have the latter part working but not sure how to find the file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedextensions

set "search= ^<ReportPath^>C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\Sage Software\Sage MAS 500 Client^</ReportPath^>"
set "replace=^<ReportPath^>\\bcshare.belterracorp.com\masreports^</ReportPath^>"

set "textFile=application.config"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: I would recommend that you do not use this method for your task. You should use a scripting language which supports the file type, syntax and content, such as [tag:powershell].

Comment: The _space_ at `set "search= ..."` becomes part of the variable value; is that on purpose?